# UICollectionView Vertical Spacing Constraint shows white bar = 20 pixels

Tags: ios, objective-c, autolayout, uicollectionview

I am trying to display all 100 4x25 UICell buttons, but the last row is only displaying half of the 4 cells when I scroll-to-stop at the bottom (imagine the bottom half of a square not showing up).  I added constraints including the Vertical Spacing Constraint, which is 20 pixels.  Now, the last row of 4 cells is all visible but my screen has the 20-pixeled constraint visible as a white bar (the entire width of my screen and 20 height).  I actually want the scroll to stop 20 pixels from the bottom, because it looks odd if I don't.

I tried to set the View (that is the super of my UICollectionView) to clear color but still nothing, the bar actually turns black.

Here's some code to show what I have in regards to layout:

```
    UICollectionViewFlowLayout *flowLayout = [[UICollectionViewFlowLayout alloc] init];
    flowLayout.sectionInset = UIEdgeInsetsMake(150, 20, 0, 20);
    [flowLayout setItemSize:CGSizeMake(55, 55)];
    [flowLayout setScrollDirection:UICollectionViewScrollDirectionVertical];

    [self.collectionView setCollectionViewLayout:flowLayout];
    self.collectionView.backgroundColor = [UIColor colorWithPatternImage:[UIImage imageNamed:@"MainScreen.png"]];
```

Any thoughts? Suggestions?  I already did the Reset to Suggested Constraints.

Answer (score 0):

Did you reset your flowLayout.sectionInset ? I think this problem happen in here:

```
flowLayout.sectionInset= UIEdgeInsetsMake(150, 20, 0, 20);
```

Can you try this code:

```
flowLayout.sectionInset= UIEdgeInsetsMake(150, 20, 0, 0);
```

In last row show hafl of image, i think you can see and reset yourCollectionView.frame (see it's autoresizeLayout). Can you try this code:

```
yourCollectionView.frame = yourContentView.frame;
yourCollectionView.autoresizingMask = UIViewAutoresizingFlexibleHeight | UIViewAutoresizingFlexibleWidth | UIViewAutoresizingFlexibleBottomMargin;
```